# disable / enable (toggle) a datepicker (range) over two radiobuttons

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a date range with two datepickers, like this demo:

[ui datepicker demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range)

but with the icon trigger on both date fields.

Now I want to disable/enable this date range with two radio buttons: 'on' and 'off' (not with a checkbox!). The icon must be disabled/enabled too (gray or not gray).

I found many things for this, but not a complete solution.

These are my radio buttons:

```
<input class="radiobutton" type="radio" id="flex_ja" value="noch" name="flex" /><label for="flex">Yes</label>
<input class="radiobutton" type="radio" id="flex_nein" value="nicht mehr" name="flex"/><label for="flex">No</label>
```

And these are my datepicker range inputs:

```
<input id="min_anreise" name="min_anreise" placeholder="Frühestes Anreisedatum"/>
<input id="max_abreise" name="max_abreise" placeholder="Spätestes Abreisedatum"/>
```

This is the javascript code from the ui demo site

```
        $(function() {
    var dates = $( "#min_anreise, #max_abreise" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {

        $('#Form').validate().element('#max_abreise');
        $('#Form').validate().element('#min_anreise');

            var option = this.id == "min_anreise" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
            });
        });
```

How can i combine this to toggle the dates with the radioboxes?

The only way to disable the date input with the icon is:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ disabled: true });
```

And the last thing:

when the dates are enables and anybody fill this out, and this gfioes to disables, ist wher fine when the inputs are cleared.

Comment: I don't understand your 'last thing'. Could you rephrase that?

Answer (score 0):

Bind an `onclick` event to your radio buttons.

In the `onclick` event handler, check the status of the radio buttons ('on' or 'off')

If 'on':

Enable your datepickers

If 'off':

Disable your datepickers

Enabling and disabling the datepickers can be done using the code that you posted:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ disabled: true });
```

Comment: Thank you,this is my resolution:

Comment: This is my resolution:
// 2. Datum ausgraubn über Radio
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 $("#min_anreise").datepicker( "disable" );
 $("#max_abreise").datepicker( "disable" );
   $("input[name=flex]").change(function () {
     if (this.value == "nicht") {
        $("#min_anreise").datepicker( "disable" );
        $("#max_abreise").datepicker( "disable" );
        $("#min_anreise").datepicker( "setDate" , null );
        $("#max_abreise").datepicker( "setDate" , null );
  } else {
   $('#min_anreise').datepicker('enable');
   $('#max_abreise').datepicker('enable');
      }
    });
 });

Comment: @user1434780 - If my answer was correct and lead you to this resolution, please accept it. If you found something different, please post this code (and a short explanation of how it solved your problem) in a separate answer and mark your answer as the accepted answer.